# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null with Integer.Parseint()

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets

*when I try to run my JSP on the server I encounter this problem...
the servlet is:

```
@WebServlet({"/Registrazione" , "/Registrazione.jsp"})
public class Registrazione extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Registrazione() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ClienteDAO d=new ClienteDAO();

        String idCliente=request.getParameter("userid");
        String nome=request.getParameter("nome");
        String cognome=request.getParameter("cog");
        String partitaIva=request.getParameter("piva");
        String codiceFiscale=request.getParameter("cf");
        String email=request.getParameter("eml");
        String fidelity=request.getParameter("fid");
        String via=request.getParameter("via");
        String numerocivico = request.getParameter("nciv");
        String password=request.getParameter("pw");



        Cliente cliente=new Cliente(Integer.parseInt(idCliente),nome,cognome,partitaIva,codiceFiscale, email,Integer.parseInt(fidelity),via,Integer.parseInt(numerocivico),password);

        d.salvaCliente(cliente);

        response.getWriter().append("utente registrato").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

and the JSP is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registrazione</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/Registrazione" name="FormRegistrazione" method="get" >
Username:<input type="text" name="userid" value="">
<br>
Nome:<input type="text" name="nome" value="">
<br>
Cognome:<input type="text" name="cog" value="">
<br>
PIVA:<input type="text" name="piva" value="">
<br>
CF:<input type="text" name="cf" value="">
<br>
email:<input type="text" name="eml" value="">
<br>
fidelity:<input type="text" name="fid" value="">
<br>
via:<input type="text" name="via" value="">
<br>
civico:<input type="text" name="nciv" value="">
<br>
password:<input type="text" name="pw" value="">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="invia">
</form>
</body>
</html>
}*
```

but when i try to run the jsp from server i see this :

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
it.unirc.twd.BuyeDrink.servlet.NuovoCliente.doGet(NuovoCliente.java:37)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

I have a similar servlet and it run very good but also with "" value in the form.
So I can't understand the problem with integer parseInt ... what's the problem?

Comment: You need to check the string values which are you attempting to parse as integers.  It's not possible, for example, to parse an empty string.  You are in the best position to do this, rather than we.

Comment: "i have a similar servlet and it run very good but also with "" value in the form." if it's just a set, sure. if it has to pass an Integer.parseInt(), it wouldn't work either, unless you are catching the Exception there some way

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It’s pretty much code to ask us to read and understand. Could you [create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? Also asking because in the proces of doing so you have a good chance to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
String x = null;    
Integer.parseInt(x) // will rase the exception
```

> Throws:
>   NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

check oracle docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

if i run this servlet :

```
@WebServlet({ "/AggiungiStudente", "/AggiungiStudente.jsp" })
public class AggiungiStudente extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public AggiungiStudente() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    StudenteDAO dao = new StudenteDAO();
    String matricola = request.getParameter("matricola");
    String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
    String cognome = request.getParameter("cognome");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String idcdl = request.getParameter("idcdl");

    Studente s = new Studente(Integer.parseInt(matricola),nome,cognome,password,Integer.parseInt(idcdl));

    dao.salvaStudente(s);       

    response.sendRedirect("/VisualizzaStudente");

    response.getWriter().append("Utente aggiunto").append(request.getContextPath());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

}

with this JSP

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="/AggiungiStudente">
<table style="height: 400px; width: 598px;border: 1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 118px;">&nbsp;Matricola:</td>
<td style="width: 473px;">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="matricola" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 118px;">&nbsp;Nome:&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 473px;">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="nome" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 118px;">&nbsp;Cognome:</td>
<td style="width: 473px;">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cognome" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 118px;">&nbsp;Password:</td>
<td style="width: 473px;">&nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 118px;">IdCdl:</td>
<td style="width: 473px;">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="idcdl" value=""></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


            <input type="submit" value="Aggiungi">
</form>         

</body>
</html>
```

when i click "Aggiungi" the value that i insert in the form are inserted in the database in oracle ... i want to make the same thing in another database